# Retrieve the value of the column excel

Tags: excel

I need your help, I would like to retrieve the value of the column where the cell contains 1 here is an example:

Image

[image]

### A | B | C | D

### 1 | 0 | 0 |

### 0 | 1 | 1 |

### 1 | 1 | 0 |

The desired result:

### A | B | C | D

### 1 | 0 | 0 | A

### 0 | 1 | 1 | B,C

### 1 | 1 | 0 | A,B

Thank you !

Comment: Easy enough with VBA. The absence of a good Excel join function (prior to Office 365's `TEXTJOIN` function) makes a spreadsheet-formula approach difficult or impossible (unless you are using Office 365). But, if the number of columns is fixed (as in your 3-column example) then a spreadsheet formula isn't too bad.

Comment: in SO you should not edit the title of the question to RESOLVED or similar, you just have to mark the answer as correct, this is indicated in the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA approach that works for any number of columns:

```
Function SelectedColumns(R As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, count As Long
    Dim cols As Variant

    n = R.Columns.count
    ReDim cols(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        If R.Cells(1, i).Value = 1 Then
            count = count + 1
            cols(count) = Split(R.Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
        End If
    Next i
    If count > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve cols(1 To count)
        SelectedColumns = Join(cols, ",")
    End If
End Function
```

Put the above code in a standard code module. The, in your example, if you enter `=SelectedColumns(A1:C1)` in cell `D1` and copy down then it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the TEXTJOIN formula that can be used in Office 365 Excel:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(A1:C1=1,{"A","B","C"},""))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead if Enter When exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

For Earlier versions you can use an if for each and concatenate:

```
=MID(IF(A1=1,",A","") & IF(B1=1,",B","") & IF(C1=1,",C",""),2,100)
```

[image]

Comment: This makes me want to upgrade to Office 365 (+1). Is there a way to combine `TEXTJOIN` with e.g. `SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")` so that your array formula works with any number of columns in any location in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @JohnColeman sure, just put that in the TRUE of the IF: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(A1:C1=1,SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1:C1),4,),"1",""),""))`

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear of your formatting (how you want the answer etc), but perhaps this will help you out a bit. 
I am assuming your headers are in cells A1 through C1, then your data in cells A2 through C4. Ane you want the data in Cells D2 to F4.

If you copy the following into cell D2 then use the drag function it will produce the result you are after.
    =IF(A2=1,A$1,"")

Have a look at the screen capture where I have displayed the formulas then another with the result displayer.

[Formulars Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfRWs.jpg)

[Just the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVuio.jpg)

Hope this helps --- Best of Luck !!!